# Indent in dark reader

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I open site on live server with dark reader(included), I have an indent from the top. picture attached.

If it helps top indent disappears when turned off

```
html, body{
background-color:#181a1b;
}
html{
background-color:#181a1b !important;
}
```

[the site itself](https://mewni1.github.io/Survey-form/)

[the problem itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yww8D.jpg)

When it's off everything is fine, however, I can't turn it off because I need it.